# Oracle Reports 6i - General Layout Properties

Tags: oracle, report, oraclereports

Hi I am using Oracle Reports Builder 6i.
I would like to know whether we can control the General Layout properties(Page Break Before, Page Protect, etc...) dynamically at run time?
I need this information for repeating frames.

Thanks
Ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change these parameters dynamically at run time.

However, what you can do is create multiple "versions" of your layout objects, and write PL/SQL triggers that conditionally show and hide each version.

Depending on what you want to do, there's usually a way to get the layout you need - but it can get tricky sometimes.

For example, if you want a particular frame to sometimes have a Page Break Before, but other times not, you might add an additional frame within it that has Page Break Before set to Yes; and put the condition on that frame. Not sure but this might work for you.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried the multiple version approach. Trying to avoid as it crowds and complicates the layout. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes, it can get quite complex. Sometimes it takes a bit of creativity, and getting the users to compromise on a simpler design.